# how do I want to fix OnClickListener1

Tags: android

this is my code. there is some error here and i couldn't settle it. can anyone pls help me?  there is an error at view.OnClickListener and View v. If i using quick fix to fix an error,another error will appear. pls help me  :'(

```
package com.android;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    import java.io.*;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.View.*;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.text.Editable;

    public class Net extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
    {  
        EditText edt;
        TextView text;
        Button ping;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) //To do auto generated method  
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt);
            text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
            ping=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ping);
            Button.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

         public void onClick(View v) //To do auto generated method  
         {
         Editable host=edt.getText();
         }
        InetAddress addr=null;
        {
                Object host;
                try
                {
                    addr=InetAddress.getByName(host.toString());
                }
        catch(UnknownHostException e) //To do auto generated catch block
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
            if(addr.isReachable (5000))
            {
                text.append("\n" +host+ "-Respond Ok");
            }
            else
            {
                text.append("\n"+host);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            text.append("\n"+e.toString());
        }


        try
        {
         String pingCmd="ping -c5"+host;
         String pingResult="";
         Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
         Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
         String inputLine;
         while((inputLine = in.readLine())!=null)
         {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
            text.setText(inputLine+"\n\n");
            pingResult += inputLine;
            text.setText(pingResult);
        }
        in.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("\t\t\t\t** Network Tracer ** \n\n\t\tWelcome to Android Network Tracer!");
            setContentView(tv);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Whats the error? Post your logcat

Comment: the error at view.OnClickListener   View v    Button.setOnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

If error is compile time then most probably here on line:

```
public void onClick(View v) //To do auto generated method  
     {
     Editable host=edt.getText();
     }
    InetAddress addr=null;
```

you have closed method definition having only statement, if you want to place all the following code into onClick method, follow as:

```
public void onClick(View v) //To do auto generated method  
     {
     Editable host=edt.getText();

    InetAddress addr=null;

            Object host;
            try
            {
                addr=InetAddress.getByName(host.toString());
            }
    catch(UnknownHostException e) //To do auto generated catch block
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try
    {
        if(addr.isReachable (5000))
        {
            text.append("\n" +host+ "-Respond Ok");
        }
        else
        {
            text.append("\n"+host);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        text.append("\n"+e.toString());
    }


    try
    {
     String pingCmd="ping -c5"+host;
     String pingResult="";
     Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
     Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
     String inputLine;
     while((inputLine = in.readLine())!=null)
     {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
        text.setText(inputLine+"\n\n");
        pingResult += inputLine;
        text.setText(pingResult);
    }
    in.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("\t\t\t\t** Network Tracer ** \n\n\t\tWelcome to Android Network Tracer!");
        setContentView(tv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) //To do auto generated method  
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt);
            text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
            ping=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ping);
            Button.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
```

with this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) //To do auto generated method  
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt);
            text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
            ping=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ping);
            ping.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
```

Comment: please send me the entire log

Comment: error at ping.setOnClickListener(have red line under setOnClickListener)